# BigQuery Materialized View - ARRAY_AGG issue

Tags: google-bigquery

We are trying to use ARRAY_AGG as a pattern for MATERIALIZED views to get the 'latest' product event for a given productId.

The SQL below is a standard pattern (well documented on this site) and works in of itself, but in the context of BigQuery MVs, fails with the attached error.

We essentially want to use this type of SQL on a materialized view, where 'latest' is incrementally updated by BQ MV, rather than the alternative of schedule queries to reprocess all the events in product_events?

```
CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `project.product_events_latest`
AS
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(
    e ORDER BY PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", event.eventOccurredTime) DESC LIMIT 1
  )[OFFSET(0)].*
FROM
  `project.product_events` e
GROUP BY
  e.productEvent.product.id
```

[image]

Im not sure what the unsupported feature is, and if there is a way to re-write to make it work differently or just isnt possible yet?  Any help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently BigQuery materialized view [does not support OFFSET](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/materialized-views-faq#error_an_internal_error_occurred_and_the_request_could_not_be_completed) and other post-computation present on top of aggregate functions.

> Instead, move [OFFSET(0)] into a regular view on top of the
> materialized view

Comment: I find even if I remove the OFFSET[0].* operator, to leave the struct, I get another error of unsupported operator 'Struct' FYI.  The 'struct' part feels the biggest blocker, as we want the full event, not 1 field, since without offset we could put another view ontop to do the offset.  

CREATE MATERIALIZED VIEW `product.product_events_latest`
AS
SELECT
  ARRAY_AGG(
    e ORDER BY PARSE_TIMESTAMP("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%E*S%Ez", event.eventOccurredTime) DESC LIMIT 1
  ) AS LatestProduct
FROM
  `product.product_events` e
GROUP BY
  e.productEvent.product.id